# Is CLEAR only for US Citizens and Permanent residents?

Tags: tsa-precheck

I am an Italian citizen and registered for CLEAR yesterday.  A friend just told me it is only for US citizens or permanent residents.  Is that true? If so should I cancel my membership in CLEAR?  Also do I need TSA-pre in addition to CLEAR?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [enrollment page](https://www.clearme.com/enroll), your friend is correct:

> CLEAR is currently only available to US citizens and legal permanent residents 18 and older with a valid photo ID.

So, unless you are a US citizen or permanent resident, you probably should cancel your registration.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain CLEAR services like the CLEAR Health pass which may be used by anyone 18 or older with a US state ID, driver license, US or international passport or a valid US permanent resident card ([Who can use CLEAR healthpass](https://www.clearme.com/support/healthpass/who-can-use-health-pass)).

A CLEAR membership is required in order to use any of these services. So technically a non citizen/permanent resident is eligible for a basic CLEAR membership.